# EF Core Async Stored Procedure Lock wait timeout exceeded

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, asynchronous, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

in my context, I'm running 2 stored procedures asynchronously using EF Core. This is causing me a deadlock and timeout issue.

Below I show the code of the mehtod that calls the other 2 that invoke the stored procedures:

```
public PortfolioPublishJobStep...

private async Task DoExecuteAsync(ProcessingContext context)
    {
        var (startDate, endDate) = GetInterval(context);

        var portfolioApiId = context.Message.ManagedPortfolioApiId;

        using var transactionScope = TransactionScopeFactory.CreateTransactionScope(timeout: Timeout, transactionScopeAsyncFlowOption: TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);

        var asyncTasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var publishableService in _publishableServices)
        {
            var asyncTask = publishableService.PublishAsync(portfolioApiId, startDate, endDate);

            asyncTasks.Add(asyncTask);
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(asyncTasks.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
```

And here below the classes/methods that invoke their respective procedures...

```
PortfolioFinancialBenchmarkDataService...

public async Task PublishAsync(string portfolioApiId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(portfolioApiId))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(portfolioApiId));
            }

            var repository = UnitOfWork.Repository<PortfolioFinancialBenchmarkData>();

            await repository.RemoveAsync(x => x.PortfolioApiId == portfolioApiId && x.ReferenceDate >= startDate && x.ReferenceDate <= endDate).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

            var parameters = new[]
            {
                DbParameterFactory.CreateDbParameter<MySqlParameter>("@PortfolioApiId", portfolioApiId),
                DbParameterFactory.CreateDbParameter<MySqlParameter>("@StartDate", startDate),
                DbParameterFactory.CreateDbParameter<MySqlParameter>("@EndDate", endDate)
            };

            await repository.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("CALL PublishPortfolioFinancialBenchmarkData(@PortfolioApiId, @StartDate, @EndDate);", parameters).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        }
```

And this:

```
PortfolioFinancialDataService...

public async Task PublishAsync(string portfolioApiId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(portfolioApiId))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(portfolioApiId));
            }

            var repository = UnitOfWork.Repository<PortfolioFinancialData>();

            await repository.RemoveAsync(x => x.PortfolioApiId == portfolioApiId && x.ReferenceDate >= startDate && x.ReferenceDate <= endDate).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

            var parameters = new[]
            {
                DbParameterFactory.CreateDbParameter<MySqlParameter>("@PortfolioApiId", portfolioApiId),
                DbParameterFactory.CreateDbParameter<MySqlParameter>("@StartDate", startDate),
                DbParameterFactory.CreateDbParameter<MySqlParameter>("@EndDate", endDate)
            };

            await repository.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("CALL PublishPortfolioFinancialData(@PortfolioApiId, @StartDate, @EndDate);", parameters).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        }
```

I believe the problem is the simultaneous connection to the database.

I thought I mitigated this using TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption, as I've seen elsewhere, but the problem persists.

During the execution of procedures, a deadlock occurs in one of the tables that one of the procedures feeds, and a timeout error occurs.

And the exception message:

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

At some point I also received the following message:

```
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): XA_RBDEADLOCK: Transaction branch was rolled back: deadlock was detected
```

Tests I performed:

- Set database timeout from 50 to 100s, Fail
- Set PortfolioPublishJobStep timeout from 2 to 3 min and PortfolioFinancialBenchmarkDataService and PortfolioFinancialDataService from 1 to 2 min, Fail
- Run only 1 of the 2 stored procedures, Success
- Run procedures synchronously, Success

Thus, I conclude that the problem may be in the opening of 2 transactions, and I believe that one may be waiting for the end of the other...

Comment: Have you tried to start transaction via BeginTransaction?

Answer (score 0):

There are many situations where Mysql causes locks. For example:

1. Performing a DML operation without commit, and then performing a delete operation will lock the table.
2. Insert and update the same piece of data in the same transaction.
3. Improper design of table index leads to deadlock in the database.
4. Long things, blocking DDL, and then blocking all subsequent operations of the same table.

**Solution**

1. Emergency method:

   1. show full processlist;killdrop the problematic process.

      - `Show full processlist; kill x;`
   2. Sometimes through the processlist, it is not possible to see where there is a lock waiting. When the two transactions are in the commit phase, it cannot be reflected in the processlist.
2. **The cure method**:

   1. select * from innodb_trx;
   2. Check **which transactions** occupy table resources.

      1. Through this method, you need to have some understanding of innodb to deal with.
      2. innodb_lock_wait_timeout: Waiting time for row-level locks of InnoDB's dml operation

         1. innodb_lock_wait_timeout refers to the longest time the transaction waits to obtain resources.

            - If the resource is not allocated after this time, it will return to the application failure; when the lock wait exceeds the set time, the following error will be reported ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction;.
            - The time unit of the parameter is seconds, the minimum can be set to 1s (generally not set so small), the maximum can be set to 1073741824 seconds, the default installation value is 50s (default parameter setting).
         2. How to modify the value of innode lock wait timeout?

            - `set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100; set global innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100;`
            - Or：Modify the parameter file/etc/my.cnf `innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50`

Comment: I found the problem...

When calling RemoveAsync, the open transaction was not closed before the execution of the stored procedure, thus, the table was locked, generating deadlock and timeout errors.

To fix this, I removed the RemoveAsync call and deleted the data inside the stored procedure, which made me gain a bit of performance as well.